# Angular Service not passing values to backend - Header Error issue

Tags: angular, express, mongoose

I can't figure out why my values aren't being passed from the angular service to the express/mongoose PATCH call. It makes it to the document in the table, but updates currentBid to null and lastBidTimeStamp and bidderId don't update.

If I use postman like this:

https://postimg.cc/1nQnX3zK

The two values don't update that way either. Only currentBid updates in postman.

I did console.log(lastBidTimeStamp) in service and it outputted date correctly so it's receiving the value in the service.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Still learning. Any help is appreciated.

bidding.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Bidding } from './bidding.model';


@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class BiddingService {


  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }


  submitBid(auctionId: string, currentBid: string, lastBidTimeStamp: Date, userId: string) {



    const bidding: Bidding = {
      id: auctionId,
      bidderId: userId,
      lastBidTimeStamp: lastBidTimeStamp,
      bidValue: currentBid
    };

    return this.http.patch(`http://localhost:3000/api/listings/${bidding.id}`, bidding,
    );

  }

}
```

app.js

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
next();
});






   app.patch('/api/listings/:id', (req, res) =>
Post.update(
  {id: req.query.id},
  {currentBid: req.body.currentBid},
  {lastBidTimeStamp: req.body.lastBidTimeStamp},
 // {bidderId: req.userData.userId}
  ).then( user => {
  console.log(user);
  res.json(user);
  // res.sendStatus(200);
  })


.then( user => {
console.log(res.json(user));
res.json(user);
// res.sendStatus(200);
}).catch(err => console.log(err)));
```

Comment: Try to use `PUT` method, not `PATCH` method

Comment: I updated it to PUT on service and app.js , but same issue

Comment: So check whether you are sending correct body of PATCH method like this `console.log(bidding)` before this row `return this.http.patch`

Comment: If i console.log(bidding) I get: https://postimg.cc/HV4Z3BRY

Comment: so it looks like it is okay at Angular side - your params are sent correctly, you need to correctly accept your params at back end side. Try to change to `app.put('/api/listings/:id', (req, res) =>`

Comment: I've tried app.put and app.patch, but same issue. Only currentBid changes and that value it changes to is null. I can use Postman like this: https://postimg.cc/1nQnX3zK to change value of currentBid to '125.00', but submitting through angular app changes it to null. No other values update.

Comment: So am I right that you are sending  at Angular side `{id: 1, bidderId: 2, bidValue: 3}`, however at back end side you are getting `{id: null, bidderId: null, bidValue: null}`?

Comment: That's correct.angular side is sending the values, but back end is sending null. I just don't know why

Comment: So I've discovered something new. If I add a console.log(res.json(user)); to the .then in app.js then I see the message. ```Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client``` I updated the code above to show my headers in app.js. I have a bunch of API calls I'm doing in app.js and I've never had issues with the header before.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the error: https://postimg.cc/nCSSpDcq

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no need to call `Post.update()` method inside of your method. 
In addition, your data is come from the front side:

[image]

[As docs of `express.js`  says:](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.put.method)

> Routes HTTP PUT requests to the specified path with the specified
>   callback functions.

So your code should looks like this:

```
app.put('/api/listings/:id', (req, res) {        
   // Retrieve the data to insert from the PUT body
   var data = [
       req.body.id,
       req.body.bidderId,
       req.body.bidValue
   ];

   // Then you can do what you want with your data

});
```

[More info about how to build REST API is can be read here.](https://medium.com/@jeffandersen/building-a-node-js-rest-api-with-express-46b0901f29b6)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the following put request

```
app.put('/api/listings/:id', (req, res) => {

Post.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id},
  {
    currentBid: req.body.currentBid,
    lastBidTimeStamp: Date.now(),
    bidderId: req.body.bidderId
  }, function(err, docs) {
    if(err) res.json(err);
    else{
      console.log(docs)
  }
  });
});
```